# To close NSStream objects before resigning active

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking, concurrency

I have an NSInputStream and NSOutputStream scheduled in a non-main-thread run loop.  I'm using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost.  The remote endpoint is an external device that communicates with the app with TCP over wifi.

When applicationWillResignActive is called, I want to close these.  I want to be guaranteed that they will close, because another app may want to communicate with the same device, and the device only accepts one TCP connection.

Additional information:

It is a frequent occurrence in the context of this device that multiple apps may need to communicate with the device.

I have tried using performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
(with waitUntilDone:YES) in applicationWillResignActive.  Sometimes this doesn't work, and in those cases it seems that the selector does not get called.

My understanding is that I can't close the NSStream objects or destroy the task queue from the main thread.

I can not change how the device receives connections.  It listens on one address/port for TCP connections, and allows only one connection (it doesn't multiplex connections by source port).

Comment: Can you dispatch_sync() to the background queue?

Comment: Yes, I can!  Thank you!  I guess you can answer and I can select your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dispatch_sync()` to the background queue.